# Set Seaborn bar color based on values not included in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with columns `x` (categorical), `y`, and `z` (both floats).

Here is my bar plot.

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x=x, y=y)
```

How can I set a color palette for the bars based on the values of the `z` column? I would like to set a Matplotlib style palette like `magma` or `RdYlBu`. Basically, like setting the `hue` argument, but with a scalar variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in seaborn. But usually using matplotlib directly works as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : list("ABCDEFGH"),
                   "y" : [3,4,5,2,1,6,3,4],
                   "z" : [4,5,7,1,4,5,3,4]})

norm = plt.Normalize(df.z.min(), df.z.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap("magma")

plt.bar(x="x", height="y", data=df, color=cmap(norm(df.z.values)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

If your "categorical" column contains pandas categories, instead of simple strings, you would first need to convert it, `df["x"] = df["x"].astype(str)`.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you! I knew some kind of normalization would would be useful, but I had no idea matplotlib had everything I needed built-in. [Here's the first plot I'm working on with this coloring method.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DHPEEUHToxJKyfxv0XSLQtZF3XkAJbbl/view)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `palette` argument that corresponds to the *hue* variable:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=z, palette='magma')
```

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data_tools = ['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia']

np.random.seed(11212018)
rand_df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': np.random.choice(data_tools, 500),
                        'INT': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500),
                        'NUM': np.random.randn(500),
                       })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
sns.barplot(data=rand_df, x='GROUP', y='NUM', hue='INT', palette='magma', ax=ax, ci=None)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="center right",)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Output]